# Filter OSM files with Osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, osmosis

I have to filter the whole Malta dataset with Osmosis only considering cycleways, footways (including used nodes of those ways) and all nodes with the tag value tourism and amenity.

I write the following, but get argument 4 and 5 error no name.

osmosis --read-xml file="malta-latest.osm.bz2" --tag filter accept-ways highway="footway","cycleway" --used-way --tag filter accept-nodes amenity --tag filter accept-nodes tourism --tag filter reject-relations --used-node --write-xml file="malta-filter.osm.bz2"

Many thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not having osmosis running on my machine right now so I'm not sure. However, you could try to remove the quotations marks from the highway values and simply seperate them with a comma. Furthermore, expand the "accept-nodes" part of your query with amenity=* and tourism=*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you more interested in the data or the tool? I always use overpass api service as the query builder is more straightforward http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API